# Valgrind detects glewInit() and glfwInit() memory leaks

Tags: c++, imagemagick, valgrind, opengl-3

Computer informations :

- NVIDIA Corporation G96M [GeForce 9600M GT]
- Linux Mint 18.2

I'm a beginner in programming with C++ and for two months I've been writting a script to generate 2D random textures with this algorithm:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080228054410/http://www.davebollinger.com/works/pixelspaceships/

I'm using OpenGL 3 (with GLEW and GLFW 3) to display the result, Magick++ to built the PNG textures and FastNoise to make the result different each time the program is executed.

With Valgrind, I got these two memory leaks (and many others very similar):

```
==2525== 10 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 11 of 1,389 
==2525==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2525==    by 0x707E489: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==2525==    by 0x8026186: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x8025F4D: _glapi_get_proc_address (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x50D8982: glXGetProcAddress (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x4E88FDC: glewInit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.13.0)
==2525==    by 0x426809: MyWindow::CreateContext(char*) (MyWindow.cpp:40)
==2525==    by 0x4266C7: MyWindow::MyWindow(char*) (MyWindow.cpp:5)
==2525==    by 0x428AF5: main (main.cpp:11)

==2525== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 200 of 1,389
==2525==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2525==    by 0x10956743: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x109FE1DA: nouveau_drm_screen_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x105654E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108C2AC0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108BDFDF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x5104232: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50DBD03: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50D7240: glXQueryVersion (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x445C54: _glfwInitGLX (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
==2525==    by 0x441B3F: _glfwPlatformCreateWindow (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
==2525==    by 0x438C14: glfwCreateWindow (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
```

MyWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MyWindow.h"

MyWindow::MyWindow(char* argv){
  CreateContext(argv);
}

void MyWindow::CreateContext(char* argv){

  Magick::InitializeMagick(argv);

  glfwInit();

  //set OpenGl version
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

  //window non resizable
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

  //get screen size
  const GLFWvidmode* screen = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
  m_Width = screen->width;
  m_Height = screen->height;

  //create window
  m_Window = glfwCreateWindow(m_Width, m_Height, "My Window", nullptr, nullptr);

  //hide cursor
  glfwSetInputMode(m_Window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN);

  //Context
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_Window);
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  glewInit();

  //Allow transparency for textures
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

MyWindow::~MyWindow(){

  Magick::TerminateMagick();
  glfwDestroyWindow(m_Window);
  glfwTerminate();
}
```

MyWindow.h:

```
#ifndef GLEW_STATIC
#define GLEW_STATIC
#endif

#ifndef MyWindow_H_Included
#define MyWindow_H_Included

//Include
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class MyWindow {

  private:

    GLFWwindow* m_Window;
    unsigned int m_Width;
    unsigned int m_Height;
    void CreateContext(char* argv);

  public:

    MyWindow(char* argv);
    ~MyWindow();
};

#endif
```

Compilation:

```
g++ -I./lib/FastNoise -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I./include `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags --ldflags --libs` -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lGL -lsfml-system -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldl -lXinerama -lX11 -lXcursor -c -o obj/MyWindow.o src/MyWindow.cpp
```

I know it's only "still reachable" memory leaks and it's not the bigger problem I could have but on this link, the author said it's "often reasonable" to free them:
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in MyWindow.cpp so that glewInit() and glfwInit() make those errors. Could they be generated by this error:

```
==2525== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==2525==
==2525== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==2525== Syscall param ioctl(generic) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==2525==    at 0x70EFF47: ioctl (syscall-template.S:84)
==2525==    by 0x90A3477: drmIoctl (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==2525==    by 0x90A624E: drmCommandWriteRead (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==2525==    by 0x11578DA0: nouveau_object_mthd (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x11579535: nouveau_device_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x109FE120: nouveau_drm_screen_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x105654E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108C2AC0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108BDFDF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x5104232: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50DBD03: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50D7240: glXQueryVersion (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==  Address 0x102ef182 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 136 alloc'd
==2525==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2525==    by 0x11578D65: nouveau_object_mthd (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x11579535: nouveau_device_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x109FE120: nouveau_drm_screen_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x105654E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108C2AC0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108BDFDF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x5104232: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50DBD03: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50D7240: glXQueryVersion (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x445C54: _glfwInitGLX (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
==2525==    by 0x441B3F: _glfwPlatformCreateWindow (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
==2525==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2525==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2525==    by 0x11578D65: nouveau_object_mthd (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x11579535: nouveau_device_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x109FE120: nouveau_drm_screen_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x105654E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108C2AC0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108BDFDF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x5104232: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50DBD03: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50D7240: glXQueryVersion (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x445C54: _glfwInitGLX (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
==2525==    by 0x441B3F: _glfwPlatformCreateWindow (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
==2525==
==2525== 5 errors in context 2 of 2:
==2525== Syscall param ioctl(generic) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==2525==    at 0x70EFF47: ioctl (syscall-template.S:84)
==2525==    by 0x90A3477: drmIoctl (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==2525==    by 0x90A624E: drmCommandWriteRead (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==2525==    by 0x11578A88: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x1157951A: nouveau_device_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x109FE120: nouveau_drm_screen_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x105654E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108C2AC0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108BDFDF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x5104232: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50DBD03: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50D7240: glXQueryVersion (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==  Address 0x102ef0f2 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 72 alloc'd
==2525==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2525==    by 0x11578A33: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x1157951A: nouveau_device_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x109FE120: nouveau_drm_screen_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x105654E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108C2AC0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108BDFDF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x5104232: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50DBD03: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50D7240: glXQueryVersion (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x445C54: _glfwInitGLX (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
==2525==    by 0x441B3F: _glfwPlatformCreateWindow (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
==2525==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2525==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2525==    by 0x11578A33: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x1157951A: nouveau_device_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==2525==    by 0x109FE120: nouveau_drm_screen_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x105654E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108C2AC0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x108BDFDF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==2525==    by 0x5104232: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50DBD03: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x50D7240: glXQueryVersion (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==2525==    by 0x445C54: _glfwInitGLX (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
==2525==    by 0x441B3F: _glfwPlatformCreateWindow (in /home/pablo/WorkSpacePerso/CppProjet/Infinite_loop_OpenGL/bin/main)
```

or this is something else ?

If you need more details, you can find the result of the command :
"valgrind -v --show-leak-kinds=all --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes bin/main"
here:

https://jumpshare.com/v/gu71bBe0RbDhyxJ8BXg6

Comment: I would guess changing `char* argv` to `const char* argv` might help.

Comment: Thank you for your participation. Unfortunaly the const keyword doesn't change anything